# Removing commutative pairs in a list in Python

Tags: python

I got a list as follows:

```
list_1 = [[3, 0], [0, 3], [3, 4]]
```

I'm trying to filter out the commutative elements in this. For example, `[3,0]` and `[0,3]` are the same and I need to keep only one of them. I tried converting this into a set, and it didn't help. I also tried iterating, but it's causing real overhead. Is there any Pythonic way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example, you can use dict comprehension:

```
>>> {tuple(sorted(t)): t for t in list_1}.values()
[[0, 3], [3, 4]]
```

Comment: Or use sets: `list(set(sorted(t) for t in list_1))`

Comment: @mg. that can return tuples not presented in original list

Comment: Yes, list are unhashable, now appreciate how smart the solution is.

Comment: I'd be interested in a solution that avoids a Python loop *and* maintains the original order of the inputs. Out of curiosity, I don't claim the questioner has requested this.

Comment: @SteveJessop withou loop I can come up only with too complicated and not very effictive `[t for i, t in sorted({tuple(sorted(t)): (i, t) for (i, t) in enumerate(list_1)}.values())]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a set of frozensets for the filtering.

If order does not matter:

```
>>> map(list, set(frozenset(t) for t in list_1))
[[3, 4], [0, 3]]
```

To retain order:

```
list_1 = [[3, 0], [0, 3], [3, 4]]
seen = set()
filtered = []
for item in list_1:
    item_set = frozenset(item)
    if item_set not in seen:
        filtered.append(item)
        seen.add(item_set)
```

Result:

```
>>> filtered
[[3, 0], [3, 4]]
```

Comment: Thank you...that's something new for me..:-)

Comment: First approach can yeild items not presented in original list too, `map(list, set(frozenset(t) for t in [[3, 0], [0, 3], [4, 3]]))`  returns `[[3, 4], [0, 3]]`. Sure it depends on the seed, and can return correct result, but this is unpredictable.

Comment: Yep, that was my comment about "if order does not matter".  Very possible that this is acceptable if differently ordered items are considered the same and are being filtered out because of that.  The second option is significantly more code, but it gives you the same order both within the elements and in the list as a whole.